# 'strict-dynamic' is present, so host-based whitelisting is disabled

Tags: security, content-security-policy, w3c

I'm loading a dummy JS script from origin like:

`<script src="http://www.this-host.test/loadMe.js"></script>`

with CSP header set to:

`script-src 'self' 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-{randomString}';`

Since the script source is comming from it's *origin host* and is allowed by `CSP` header than `loadMe.js` should load and execute.

Instead I get:

```
Refused to load the script 'http://www.this-host.test/loadMe.js' because it 
violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-{randomString}';. 
'strict-dynamic' is present, so host-based whitelisting is disabled.
```

tested on `Macintosh; Mac OS X 10_15_2`, browsers `Chrome/79.0.3945.117, Firefox/71.0`.

I don't get this message on `Safari` though.

*Perhaps good to note that I'm testing it locally.*

---

Anyway I don't want to use `nonce-{randomString}` when `CSP` header allows resources to be loaded from *origin host*.

Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [csplite.com](http://csplite.com/csp104/) server with CSP header `script-src 'self' 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-{randomString}'` set...

> 'strict-dynamic' only works in conjunction with 'hash-value' or 'nonce-value', and if they are absent, all scripts on the page will be disabled, because 'strict-dynamic' overrides the 'unsafe-inline' action and disables whitelisting of host-based sources, including the 'self' token

... which tells me that If my `loadMe.js` file is loading another file (or it doesn't have to) `nonce="{randomString}"` attribute in HTML tag must be set no matter if the file is loaded from same host or whitelisted host.